# Determine if http request is coming from a scheduled task or a browser (ASP)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, scheduled-tasks

I am building a Intranet application using ASP/C# to perform a specific job. However I have two requirements

1. I would like to be able to call the webpage from a browser and have a form to allow the user to run the service manually.
2. However I also need a scheduled task to be ran twice a day that calls the webpage and runs the service automatically 'onvisit' (without the need for a form submission)

I could easily meet requirement 1 OR 2. But I want to meet both conditions.

Note: We cannot create a separate .EXE file that runs the needed code.Also, only as a final choice would I want to make two separate webpages.

Comment: Either parameterize the querystring as already mentioned, or add a custom header in your scheduled task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parametrize the service and put the params in the querystring so when you call it from the exe it behave as expected.

Comment: It should be in comment